# Databricks upload data in batch

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, batch-processing

We all know that via the Databricks Data / Table UI we can upload data using **Create a table using file upload** for small files.

Does Databricks have a standard batch approach for large files? Or do we need to use `sFTP`, hadoop `distcp`, some sort of `REST Service?` I want to make sure I have not missed some new development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual recommendation is to use cloud-specific tools for copying/moving data to the cloud - azcopy, [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), aws-cli, etc.  These tools are usually heavily optimized for high throughput & parallelism.

Upload to DBFS should be really limited to small files when people want to do data exploration (technically you can upload files to DBFS, for example by using Databricks CLI, but it's not heavily optimized for huge amounts of data).

Comment: First 2 of interest. ADF is ssis in the cloud? Thx

Comment: ADF Copy tool supports a big number of sources. I've seen companies copying data with ADF from on-premise FTP or Samba to ADLS, etc.